# curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid

Tags: django, apache

Guys I'm trying to solve this issue and I'm kinda desperate now after failing so many times. I am trying to deploy my django app on apache I configured a license but I am getting this error curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help, I got this error when I tried to connect to an HTTP server via HTTPS protocol.